# python replace space with char if not specific chars in between

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have the following string:

`"A and B Z or C and not D E"`

My goal is to replace the space between two letters (it should also work for normal sub-strings, e.g. apple) with a `'-'` if there is no operator (`and, or, not`) in between. The string-size is not fixed.

goal: `"A and B-Z or and not D-E"`

I tried using .replace or regex, but I could not get it right. Would be glad to receive some help on that!

Comment: What happened to `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the operators are in small while the other chars are capitalized, you can use

```py
import re
s = "A and B Z or C and not D E"
s = re.sub("(?<=[A-Z]) +(?=[A-Z])", "-", s)
print(s)
```

here,
`(?<=[A-Z])` is a lookbehind for a capitalized char while `(?=[A-Z])` is a lookahead expression for capitalized char
`' +'` matches one or more spaces
and then this is substituted with `'-'`

You may want to read more about regex. Good Luck!

Comment: thank you, this is what I needed.